# How to do Google Transliteration for dynamic text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

How to use google transliteration for dynamic text fields?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Load the Google Transliteration API
google.load("elements", "1", { packages: "transliteration" });

function onLoad() {     
var options = { sourceLanguage: 'en', destinationLanguage: 'ta', shortcutKey: 'ctrl+m', transliterationEnabled: true };

// Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
var control = new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

// Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.
var ids = ['temrorary_address','permanant_address','bankbranch','member_name','father_husband','workingoffice_address','name1' ];
control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

// Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between
// English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
control.showControl('translControl');
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
</script>
```

Comment: Please Don't Start Every Single Word With An Uppercase Letter